# Evaluation of the integral $\int_{-6}^{-3}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

How to evaluate the following integral?

I have tried the following things but I have no idea to continue after the last step. Moverover, the integral seems wrong when compared with the ans from  WolframAlpha app.

$$=\int_{-6}^{-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}\over x}\,dx$$

Substitute $u=\sqrt{x^2-9}\implies du ={x\over \sqrt{x^2-9}}$

$$=\int_{x=-6}^{x=-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}\over x}\cdot{\sqrt{x^2-9}\over x}\,dx$$

$$=\int_{x-6}^{x=-3}{x^2-9 \over x^2}\,du$$

$$=\int_{x=-6}^{x=-3}{u^2\,du \over u^2 + 9}$$

$$=\int_{x=-6}^{x=-3}{du\over 1 + \left(\frac3{u}\right)^2}$$

$$=\left[\tan^{-1}\left({3\over \sqrt{x^2-9}}\right)\right]_{-6}^{-3}$$

$$=\pi/2$$

While [WolframAlpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jFA6.png) gives $\pi -3\sqrt{3}$

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsILS.jpg) is a link to my original work

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: why haven't you changed the limits after substitution?

Comment: @ketan - Do you mean line 5 and 6?

Comment: yea, after substitution

Comment: Why don't you use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution  from the start?

Comment: I took some time to edit your work(to make it more suitable for math.se format). Will you check to see if it is the same?

Comment: Yes, I will check it.

Comment: Also in one  step you write $\tan^{-1}(\infty)-\tan^{-1}({3\over \sqrt{27}}) = \pi/2$. That is wrong. $\tan^{-1}(1\over \sqrt{3}) = \pi/6$. So your subtraction should give $\pi/3$

Comment: oop. that should have been $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\right) =\pi/6$

Comment: The function that you're integrating is *negative* in the interval $-6 \le x \le -3$, so one can say without any calculations that your *positive* answer $\pi/2$ can't be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your antiderivative is incorrect. You can see this by differentiating $\arctan (\frac{3}{u})$; you will not get the original integrand back. I recommend performing long division on $\frac{u^2}{u^2+9}$ to receive $1-\frac{9}{u^2+9}$. Proceed from there and you will arrive at the correct answer.

And you should also change the bounds of integration appropriately.

Comment: I get my indefinite integral like this : $\sqrt{x^2-9}+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{3}\right)+c$... =[

Comment: You might want to remember [this identity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\arctan%28x%29%2B\arctan%281%2Fx%29%3Dpi%2F2), which if you absorb the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the integration $c$ should help you get closer to Wolfram's integral. I guess you lost a $-3$ somewhere, because there should be one before that arctangent…

Answer (score 1):

According to me answer is

$ 3√3 - \pi$
[image]

As According to Wolfram Alpha answer is

$\pi - 3√3$.

So I doubt I might have made a mistake but I am not able it find it.

Comment: The original integrand is negative, so the answer should clearly be negative. So, your answer is wrong. PS Please write your answer in [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here instead of inserting images.

Answer (score 0):

Let us see. We have to evaluate:
$$I=\int_{-6}^{-3}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x}\mathrm{d}x.$$
You suggest substituting $u=\sqrt{x^2-9}$, thus getting $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}\mathrm{d}x\implies\mathrm{d}u=\frac{u}{-\sqrt{u^2+9}}\mathrm{d}u$. The minus is due to the fact that we are integrating over $[-6,-3]$ where $x<0$ and the root would be positive. Plug that in and we get:
$$I=\int_{\sqrt{27}}^0\frac{u}{-\sqrt{u^2+9}}\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+9}}\mathrm{d}u=\int_{3\sqrt3}^0\frac{u^2}{u^2+9}\mathrm{d}u=u\Big|_{3\sqrt3}^0-\int_{3\sqrt3}^0\frac{9}{u^2+9}\mathrm{d}u.$$
The first piece evaluates to $-3\sqrt3$. For the second piece we let $t=\frac{u}{3}$, whence $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{3}$. That bit therefore becomes:
$$-\int_{3\sqrt3}^0\frac{-9}{u^2+9}\mathrm{d}u=-3\int_{\sqrt3}^0\frac{1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{d}t=-3\arctan(t)\Big|_{\sqrt3}^0=3\arctan(\sqrt3).$$
So the integral finally becomes:
$$I=-3\sqrt3+3\arctan(\sqrt3)=-3\sqrt3+3\frac{\pi}{3}=\pi-3\sqrt3.$$
Your mistake was when you said:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+\left(\frac3u\right)^2}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac3u\right).$$
The integral of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ is the arctangent, but there you don't have that, to have that you'd need $\mathrm{d}\!\left(\frac3u\right)$, but you have $\mathrm{d}u$, which is not the same.

Comment: As an antiderivative, I get $\sqrt{x^2-9}-3\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{3}\right)+c$, which by using that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ for $x\neq0$ will get me to Wolfram's indefinite integral if I absorb the extra $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ into the constant. Where by $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ I denote the sign function, $\frac{x}{|x|}$.